# Chef Recipe Compile Error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

Does anyone know why the following code results the error: **undefined method 'tar' for "riak-1.4.2":String**

```
remote_file "/vagrant/usr/src/#{node.default['riak']['version'].tar.gz}" do
  source "#{node.default['riak']['url']}"
  mode 0755
  notifies :run, "bash[extract_riak]", :immediately
end

bash "extract_riak" do 
  code <<-EOH
    # Following is the line which causes the error.
    /bin/tar xzf /vagrant/usr/src/#{node.default['riak']['version']}.tar.gz -C /vagrant/usr/src/#{node.default['riak']['version']}
  EOH
  notifies :run, "bash[make_riak]", :immediately
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is raising the error:

```
remote_file "/vagrant/usr/src/#{node.default['riak']['version'].tar.gz}"
```

The `.tar.gz` should be outside the brackets, like so:

```
remote_file "/vagrant/usr/src/#{node.default['riak']['version']}.tar.gz"
```

Everything between the brackets is executed as ruby code and the result takes it's place in the string. `node.default['riak']['version'].tar.gz` is a chain of function calls, including calling a non-existent `tar` and `gz` function at the end. These are part of the filename, and should go outside the brackets.

As a side note, you probably want to use `node[:attribute]` to *get* attributes, and only use `node.default[:attribute]` to *set* attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [ark cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ark) as better choice for handling archives.

The following example recipe:

```
include_recipe "ark"

ark "riak" do
  url "http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/riak/1.4/1.4.2/riak-1.4.2.tar.gz"
  version "1.4.2"
end
```

will install riak under the "/usr/local/riak-1.4.2" directory.

Finally, there is a [riak cookbook](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/with-chef/) available as well, which reportedly will also install from source.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
#{node.default['riak']['version']}.tar.gz
```

you want:

```
#{node.default['riak']['version'].tar.gz}
```

Comment: If `remote_file "/vagrant/usr/src/#{node.default['riak']['version'].tar.gz}"` worked, then I don't see why my answer shouldn't work.  However, I will say that I've no experience with Chef, I'm just  hunting down what looks suspicious.